# AngularJS - Changing text of default option inside ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select menu using `ng-options` to repeat the options, and I have a default `<option>` inside the menu:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="d.id as d.value for d in data">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
</select>
```

**Problem:** I want to make it so that the text inside that default option changes based off another property in the `$scope`, and I tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="d.id as d.value for d in data">
  <option value="" ng-if="!optional">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="" ng-if="optional">Choose an option (optional)</option>
</select>
```

It seems it will only show one default `<option>` element, so I also tried the following with `ng-show` but it doesn't work either:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="d.id as d.value for d in data">
  <option value="">Choose an option <span ng-show="optional">(optional)</span></option>
</select>
```

I know you can also do `<option ng-repeat>` inside the select menu, but the data for the options comes from an AJAX call and doesn't update correctly when the data first comes in, so I'm sticking to using `<select ng-options>`.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udu9byka/1/) with the problem.

Any suggestions for how I could go about getting this to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first try didn't work because, as said by [the documentation of `select` in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), only "a **single** hard-coded `<option>` element can be nested into the `<select>` element".

Your second try didn't work because the [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) element can only receive "text (with eventually escaped characters like `&eacute;`)" as content, and not any tag like the `<span>` you've tried.

The solution is simply to use interpolation:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="d.id as d.value for d in data">
    <option value="">Choose an option {{optional ? '(optional)' : ''}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there way to change a selected value of a select cause I'm trying to update a record and some values needs to be set in selected option?

Comment: @gayan1991 Yes, simply do something like `filterFilter(data, {id : selected}, true).value = "New value of the selected option"`. But that's a whole new question ; please post it as such. I'll then be happy to help :).

Comment: @Blackhole thanks. actually it was my part of the problem. The object i was assigning is not in the list, so it is not getting selected at all

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the text with template markup?

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="d.id as d.value for d in data">
  <option value="">{{defaultOptionText}}</option>
</select>
```

Working at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/udu9byka/2/

Comment: Please don't use the code snippet functionality without providing a functional snippet.

Comment: @Blackhole, thanks!  I changed it to use the "Code Sample" format.